# A water molecule happens when two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom meet together

Tags: word-usage

A water molecule is made up of two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom.

Can I change this sentence into this sentence? (Semantic correctness, not naturalness.)

A water molecule **happens** when two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom meet together.

Comment: An event happens; we don't usually say that a thing, such as a molecule, happens. You could say "The creation of a water molecule happens..."

Comment: @Kate Bunting But is it possible?

Comment: @Michael Harvey I’m learning about generative grammar.

Comment: People sometimes use 'happens' loosely, e.g. "love happens when two people meet who are meant for each other".

Comment: It still sounds like a catalyst might be needed.

Comment: I'm not a chemist, but I suspect that if I filled a gas jar with 2 parts hydrogen and one part oxygen, a ***water*** molecule might be created once in a blue moon using energy from cosmic rays or similar. But you'd need incredibly good detection equipment to actually ***find*** any water in the jar.

Comment: From a scientific point of view, saying that ""The creation of a water molecule happens when two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom meet together" is such an over-simplification that I would not even use it in elementary material for young children. You can't just mix hydrogen and oxygen and make water. If you could, we'd all be dead, millions of years ago, from drowning if not anoxia (that's a silly way of putting it, I know). Simply put, you need a catalyst, as fuel-cell researchers will tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't really idiomatic, no. Events or processes 'happen', but you are referring to the final compound that is caused by an event, not the event itself.

In simple language, you might be better saying:

> A water molecule *is created* when two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom meet together.

Scientific processes could be termed 'events' and so you could say that these 'happen', although 'occur' is a more likely choice in the context. I believe the process of atoms combining is called *chemical bonding*, so you could say:

> When two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom meet together *chemical bonding occurs* and forms a water molecule.

There might well be a more scientific way to put this.

Comment: *Meet together* sounds like something a learner would say.  I have said *meet together* zero times in the last two decades.  *A water molecule is created when two hydrogen atoms and one oxygen atom **combine**.*